# Disable item from dropdownlist with session until button is clicked

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i need to create drop-down list in asp.net with items from sql database, which display all items but some of them disable for select.

For example if user choose the DDL.Items[1] and press the button --> 1 will enabled but other items will disabled until pressed the STOP button.if user choose DDL.Items[2] and press button --> 2 will be enabled and other items will be disabled. And I need to do that with session. If user close the windows and get back DDL.Items[1] will still enabled and other items will still disabled. How can I do that ? Thank you.

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: why you thinking like that ? i dont understand

Comment: I know i should use collection items and make foreach loop for that , but dont know how. cause of that i ask this question. why are you so negative ?

Comment: its just required 4 or 5 columns of code just i dont know what to write -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was ; Thanks for no one helping.

```
int x = 0;
foreach (ListItem lst in DDLisSec.Items)
{
if (x != DDLisSec.SelectedIndex)
{
lst.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;");
lst.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");

}
x++;
}
```